# Remove edit access to account name in Salesforce B2B Site

Tags: css, lightning-community, b2b-lex

I do not want Community Users able to edit their Account Name in the B2B storefront.

- I am unable to remove edit access on their community profiles
- I cannot remove edit access via page layout or even remove the field from the layout

I suspect that I could use css to remove it's edibility. I could add a validation rule but hoping to improve the customer experience.

Any tips or ideas? [image: Account Name shows pencil icon and is editable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this done with CSS. I added the following line to remove the pencil icon from showing next to the Account name:

```
.test-id__inline-edit-trigger[title = "Edit Account Name"].inline-edit-trigger[title = "Edit Account Name"]{
display:None;
}
```

I also added a validation rule so that if they get lucky and double click on the Account Name it won't allow the change to be made.